# Calling a function of a property in extension object of xslt 1.0

Tags: c#, xslt-1.0

this is my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"                    
                xmlns:MyUtils="pda:MyUtils"
                exclude-result-prefixes="MyUtils">
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <Envelope>
          <xsl:variable name="entityData" select="..//ArrayOfEntityRow"/>
          <xsl:variable name="data" select="MyUtils:get_data().GoodData()"/>    
        </Envelope>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the extension class

```
    class MyExtension
    {
        public MyExtension()
        {
            data = new Data();
        }

        public Data data
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    class Data
    {
        public string GoodData()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error `"Extension function parameters or return values which have Clr type 'Data' are not supported."` Though I am returning string from GoodData() function.
I want to access GoodData() function from xslt..How can I do it?

The extension object added to the XSLT is of type "MyExtension" not "Data"

Comment: Hello @DanielA.White  this is not duplicate of the previously asked question. I had gone through that link previously

Comment: have you looked into returning one of the types listed on the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046957/23528? it sounds like theres only a few things you can return and `Data` isnt one of them.

Comment: I cannot add the function MyExtension class..
The function must exist in Data class..
Also MyExtension needs to be extension object to xslt