# Read and selecting Css Style attribute values

Tags: c#, linq, xslt, .net-3.5, xpath

How can I read an element/ tag like below - using xsl + xpath, I am trying to format the xml output to read the alignment tag from the style attribute, but I cannot figure it out... (last resort c#)

**EDIT**: To make my answer clear, I could be reading many html documents, I will most likely have a list of allowed tags that I need parsing so not everything will need parsing, as I am using xslt to transfortm teh document into xml I am writing my solution so far keeping only xsl + xpath in mind, however if I was to use c# and linq (to iterate over the document) - obviously that will set up all the styles then I will transform my document with other additions.

```
<h1 style="text-align: right;">Another chapter</h1>
```

My Xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="h1">
    <fo:block color="black" font-family="Arial, Verdana, sans-serif">
      <xsl:call-template name="set-alignment"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="set-alignment">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@align='left'">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">start</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@align='center'">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@align='right'">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">end</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note, there is only one style defined below, but there could be many... (underline etc.)

Desired output:

```
<h1 text-align="start" text-decoration="underline" >Another chapter</h1>
```

Comment: With .NET 3.5 you could consider to move to XSLT 2.0 (you can choose between Saxon 9 http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, XQSharp http://www.xqsharp.com/, or AltovaXML Tools http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html), then you could process the CSS style attribute with e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@style, ';')"><xsl:attribute name="{normalize-space(substring-before(., ':'))}" select="normalize-space(substring-after(., ':'))"/></xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: anything with budget constraints in mind... :) They look like they require a commercial license if ones application is not o/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the well known tokenization pattern, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[name()!='style']"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tokenize-style">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="string(@style)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($pString)"/>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pString,';')">
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                         select="substring-before($pString,';')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-style">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pString"
                         select="substring-after($pString,';')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="{normalize-space(
                                         substring-before($pString,':')
                                      )}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
                                             substring-after($pString,':')
                                          )"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<h1 text-align="right">Another chapter</h1>
```

Comment: genius! well known tokenization pattern in xsl... never found the reference to it anywhere...

Comment: @Haroon: I'm glad it was hepful. Some of the firsts references I could find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018974/tokenizing-and-sorting-with-xslt-1-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136500/does-xslt-have-a-split-function