# XSLT :Create New element after split at new line character

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

We have Input XML. WE want to split OrderDescription element at new line character into different part such that it will create  new substring as Comment element IN Output  XML.

Let's say Number of string is 6 . so , it should create 6 new comment element in Stockline element in output XML.

that is 
for ex  new tag portion should be created on each split

```
 <StockLine>
            <StockCode></StockCode>
            <Comment>Some Comment as split string</comment>
            </StockLine>
```

Also OrderDetail is Repeating node here. and it is important to have Each comment associated with  StockCode element is empty.

**Input XML :**

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
  <Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <Customer>000016</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2016-04-19</OrderDate>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode>ABB-CDE-FGH-01</StockCode>
        <OrderDescription>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS
        C3 Generic
LOC 0833
Expected arrival 01/07/2016
 OTYPE NE
TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</OrderDescription>
        <OrderLineID>OR-1561179</OrderLineID>
    </StockLine>
     </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

**We have applied XSLT AS:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="StockLine">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="StockCode"/>
        <NComment>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize(../StockLine[1]/OrderDescription, '\n')[$i])"/>
        </NComment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="OrderLineID"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output XML:**

```
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
  <Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
      <Customer>000016</Customer>
      <OrderDate>2005-04-19</OrderDate>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411324</SalesForceOrderNumber>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
     <StockLine>
        <StockCode></StockCode>
        <Comment>EDIORDER-SAVE COMMENTS</comment>
       </StockLine>
      <StockLine>
        <StockCode></StockCode>
        <Comment>C3 Generic</comment>
      </StockLine>
        <StockLine>
        <StockCode></StockCode>
        <Comment>LOC 0833</comment>

      </StockLine>
        <StockLine>
        <StockCode></StockCode>
        <Comment>Expected arrival 01/07/2016</comment>

      </StockLine>
        <StockLine>
        <StockCode></StockCode>
        <Comment>OTYPE NE</comment>

      </StockLine>

     <StockLine>
        <StockCode></StockCode>
        <Comment>TRKPC 01 GM/00007643020008361321</comment>

      </StockLine>
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Try to adapt the first stylesheet in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38160578/252228 to this problem, it is nearly doing what you ask for here.

Comment: Here After adopting the first stylesheet  getting this : http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqt/5

Comment: Well, your input data is slightly different, but if you adapt the path to `<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(StockLine/OrderDescription, '\n')">` then you get the new elements created. You need some more edits, but I think you should be able to adjust a path or a literal result element on your own.

Comment: After applying this : getting following error:: http://paste.ofcode.org/f7w5f5ZivbcDLRfnaZakg7

Comment: @MartinHonnen   i  just searched one post from stackoverflow .you answered  previously.   : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453956/how-to-process-a-sequence-with-one-or-more-items/35458867

Comment: I get no such error in http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqt/6 so you probably have a different input document. Make sure you select only one element as the first argument to tokenize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116554/discussion-between-vickps-and-martin-honnen).