# XSLT to wrap XML tags around some free text

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a function that returns some unformatted text. The next bit of processing requires the data to be in an XML format.  I'm thinking that XSLT would be able to add some XML tags either side of the text, but I'm struggling to find an example and to bend the examples I can find into something that works.

A as example, the text I'd want to process would look something like:

```
This is the first line of some unformatted text.
This is another.
…
…
This is the last line.
```

The output I'm looking for would look something like:

```
<TextItems>
  <TextItem name="Returned Text">
    This is the first line of some unformatted text.
    This is another.
    …
    …
    This is the last line.
  </TextItem>
</TextItems>
```

Is this possible with XSLT?
If so, how should it be done?

Comment: If you can use XSLT-2.0 or above, there's the `unparsed-text(..)` function. Here's an example: ["XSL transform on text to XML with unparsed-text"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20820301/1305969).

Comment: Thank you @zx485 that's interesting. I think I have only XSLT-1.0 available as I only have XPATH-1.0 (I assume they're linked). Regards,

Comment: Have you considered the easiest way of just concatenating the text values? Like `<TextItems>
  <TextItem name="Returned Text">` + text file contents + `</TextItem>
</TextItems>` > newFile.xml

Comment: @zx485 My environment is not a traditional programming environment.  I can pass the unformatted text as a string to something that can process XSLT … I'm not sure if the syntax you're suggesting is possible with XSLT, nor how I would refer to the text in the centre of the expression. Are you able to show a full expression?  Regards,

Comment: The best I found searching is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110529/1305969) with viable approaches for text handling.

Comment: Ah - that looks interesting. So, XSLT 1.0 needs valid XML as input - which is why I was struggling - but there are some ways to work around that.  Thanks and regards,