# Plain text file to be taken as input to an XSL

Tags: xslt

Have a plain text file with terms and conditions mentioned in it. Have to read it in XSL. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have to do this with XSLT? Maybe at least a pre-processing step to transform the input into XML? What do you need to do with the input file? Just copy/include verbatim or process somehow?

Comment: I Just need to display the file as it is. The reason input is taken as a file is so that the file can be easily modified.

Comment: I already have a XML file which is generated by the system. But the requirement is not to include the contents in the XML. Instead, take it from an input text file.

Comment: Yes have to do it with XSLT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular text file to XML using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675889/regular-text-file-to-xml-using-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

Providing you are using an XSLT 2.0 (or later) processor such as XmlPrime or Saxon 9, you can use the unparsed-text function.  Quoting the specification:

"The fn:unparsed-text function reads an external resource (for example, a file) and returns a string representation of the resource."

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using XSLT 1.0. It will require unnecessary time for transforming text file to XML format.